# exif_imagetype on broken url gives 500 internal server error in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, exif

Regular PHP file:

```
<?php

$test = exif_imagetype('http://www.example.com/some_broken_link.jpeg');

var_dump($test);

?>
```

The result:

```
bool(false)
```

Codeigniter controller:

```
class test extends CI_Controller {

    function index() {

        $test = exif_imagetype('http://www.example.com/some_broken_link.jpeg');

        $data = array(

            'test' => $test

        );

        $this->load->view('test', $data);

    }

};
```

Doing a `var_dump($test)` in the views file

```
HTTP Error 500 Internal server error
```

Now when I replace 'some_broken_link.jpeg' with 'some_working_link.jpeg', the regular php file **and** the Codeigniter view file show int(2).

PHP error's are ON, checked Apache/PHP log's, but nothing show's up. Just this 500 Int error on Codeigniter when I use the broken link.

Anyone know what's going on? I need the bool(false) in code igniter.

Comment: wrap it in a `try catch` block?

Comment: Same result with try catch, 500 on the broken link, int(2) on the working link.